# Undefined reference to `mysql_init' , Undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect using MYSQL C++ in codeblock

Tags: c++, mysql, database, mysql-connector

I added mysql.a in Project->Build Options->Linker Settings->path to mysql.a

I added "include files containing mysql.h" in Project->Build Options->Linker Settings->path to incldue files.

I also added mysql.dll files in debug folder of the project directory.

But still I am getting this error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in wss4 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
D:\C++Ws\ws4\wss4\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `mysql_init'|
D:\C++Ws\ws4\wss4\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I am using codeblock 17.12, also tried codeblock 20(latest version) but still getting the same error.

Below is my small code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

MYSQL* conn;
conn=mysql_init(0);
conn=mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","admin","admin","youtube",0,NULL,0);

if(conn){
    cout<<"Connected";
}

else{
    cout<<"Not connected";
}

}
```

Please any one show the problem solving steps. It has been taking hours and hours. Thanks

Comment: Which part of [this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) *didn't* you do?

Comment: It is just a small code, it will print "Connected" as output to the database in xamp That's all the code, but output is showing undefined reference to mysql_init(), –

Comment: Hi any solution, I have been trying still and could not find the fix.